# Collection view cell, didSelectItem delegate

Tags: swift, collectionview

i have a collectionView with images in cells and by tapping on the item i am deleting it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
                cell.image.center.x += 300 }
        } completion: { Bool in
            ImageModel.images.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
```

I can delete 1,2,3 cells, but if i scroll it downside sometimes i see on cells that they already moved (like the method UIView.animate was used, but without completion of it) Why is it happens?

Comment: Probably cell is being reused, why not just delete item like just doing ImageModel.images.remove(at: indexPath.row). only this much code is enough

Comment: also try prepareForReuse() function in you cell subclass and write image.center.x = 0. When cells will be resused, they will reset back to original position and when you tap on them, they will animate and move sideways and image will delete.

Comment: Thank you, could i ask 1 more question? About this topic. why can this happens? I added all that u said
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679269/deleting-cell-in-collectionview-bug-image-overlaid-on-image

Comment: try without reloading collectionView after deletion of item.

Comment: got the same result :c

Comment: it happens because of this code collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath]). But i need animation of this method so thats why i left it

Comment: no those are fine. I tested that code, it deletes fine with animation in my case

Comment: you are fetching data when scrolling? maybe test by fetching data when view is loaded and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yeah, i also tried that too, looks better but sometimes i got flickering image instead of overlaying images on top of each other

Comment: with the code you provided, this much should have solved the issue. Could be layout issue then but not sure